# Google Bigquery load data with local file size limit

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Is there any limit on Google Bigquery load data with a local file with API?

As Google Bigquery document mention regarding Web UI, local file size is than <=10 MB and 16,000 Rows. Is the same limit will apply to API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no BigQuery API to load local files.  Local file load via bq command or Web UI - and I believe what happened when you do this - it is just upload file to GCS on your behalf and after this just doing normal API load job from GCS - you can see it clearly in UI. But because Google want to have reasonable user experience from WebUI/bq command - additional much more strict limits are here for upload "local" files.

My recommendation to go GCS path to load big files
(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage)
Important thing - it is free (compare with streaming where you will pay for streamed data)

> ```
>     Limits are following (from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas)
>     Load jobs per table per day — 1,000 (including failures)
>     Maximum columns per table — 10,000
>     Maximum size per load job — 15 TB across all input files for CSV, JSON, and Avro
>     Maximum number of files per load job — 10 Million total files including all files matching all wildcard URIs
>     For CSV and JSON - 4 GB compressed file, 5TB uncompressed
> ```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local 
I am talking about this aspect.

Comment: I will check things

Answer (score 1):

There are no special limits for local file uploads, 10MB and 16000 rows is only for UI. But I don't recommend uploading huge local files.

Comment: Is there any strong reason? Or we can go for stream options. (I am looking either of this ). 
Or We can go with Google Cloud Storage option.

Comment: There is no BigQuery API to load local files and you ask "Is the same limit will apply to API?". Local file load via bq command or Web UI - and believe what happened when you do this - it is just upload file to GCS on your behalf and after this just doing normal API load job from GCS - you can see it clearly in UI. So it means all limits that exist for BQ Load API applied here.

Comment: Streaming and loading data with a load job both have pros and cons, so it all depends on your use case. Loading huge local files is just going to be very slow.

Comment: Actually, In my case some cases huge data loading, some cases less data loading on daily and weekly bases. I not getting a clear idea about when to use GCS, Local, Stream. I read the document but didn't get clarity. If possible, you can help me on that.