# Is there (still) an advantage to staging data on Google Cloud Storage before loading into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a data set stored as a local file (~100 GB uncompressed JSON, could still be compressed) that I would like to ingest into BigQuery (i.e. store it there).

Certain guides (for example, https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/google-bigquery-the/9781492044451/ch04.html) suggest to first upload this data to Google Cloud Storage before loading it from there into BigQuery.

Is there an advantage in doing this, over just loading it directly from the local source into BigQuery (using `bq load` on a local file)? It's been suggested in a few places that this might speed up loading or make it more reliable ([Google Bigquery load data with local file size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50153990/7391782), [most reliable format for large bigquery load jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55463433/7391782)), but I'm unsure whether that's still the case today. For example, according to its documentation, BigQuery supports resumable uploads to improve reliability (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#resumable), although I don't know if those are used when using `bq load`. The only limitation I could find that still holds true is that the size of a compressed JSON file is limited to 4 GB (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, having data in Cloud Storage is a big advantage during development. In my cases I often create a BigQuery table from data in the Cloud Storage multiple times till I tune up all things like schema, model, partitioning, resolving errors etc. It would be really time consuming to upload data every time.

**Cloud Storage to BigQuery**

Pros

- loading data is incredibly fast
- possible to remove BQ table when not used and import it when needed (BQ table is much bigger than plain maybe compressed data in Cloud Storage)
- you save your local storage
- less likely fail during table creation (from local storage there could be networking issues, computer issues etc.)

Cons

- you pay some additional cost for storage (in the case you do not plan to touch your data often e.g. once per month - you can decrease price to use the nearline storage)

So I would go for storing data to the Cloud Storage first but of course, it depends on your use case.

Comment: Is recommended use Cloud Storage in order to optimize storage in BigQuery as you can see on this document https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage ,also, you could take a look on the cost optimization best practices for BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/cost-optimization-best-practices-for-bigquery

Comment: Thanks for the insights and pointers! I can't really find a strong case for passing through Cloud Storage while reading the "best practices" - to the contrary, it suggests to not export data to Cloud Storage but instead keep it in long-term BigQuery storage. In any case, I'm asking about importing data, not exporting it. The only pros I think are relevant to me are 1) faster loading and 2) fewer fails. Do you have any sources to back this up? I'm specifically wondering whether there haven't been any recent improvements to BigQuery that make those concerns no longer valid.

Comment: from my point of view best source that can back this up is daily usage - when you are using BQ daily you will find best approach fits you where important variable is time consumption of task you want achieve and GCP costs. There is not exact recommendation for all types of tasks

Comment: I understand that not all Google solutions are the most suitable solution for all scenarios, however, just consider that the command line for bigquery (such as data loading) are more optimized for the use of cloud storage, also consider another features like VPC or IAM 
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles